# How to prevent my screens from turning off, when the screen is locked?

Tags: 13.04, screen, power-management, monitor

I would like to have my screen fully powered at all times, but it goes to standby once I lock my PC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open your System Settings. We need to make changes to *Power* and *Brightness & Lock* settings.

[image: System Settings]

#### Power Settings

Change the value of *Suspend when inactive for* to *Don't suspend*.

[image: Power Settings]

#### Brightness & Lock Settings

Change the value of *Turn screen off when inactive for* to *Never*.

[image: Brightness & Lock Settings]

This should help to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Thanks. For my particular issue (my speakers which were powered by the monitor would turn off when the screen gets locked) I just had to disable a setting of the display itself. Still, this answers the question I asked.

Answer (score 3):

I had to install additional screensaver program XScreenSaver and use it instead of default one because accepted answer had no effect for me on Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10.

1. Install XScreenSaver:

   ```
    sudo apt install xscreensaver
   ```
2. Add this command to Startup Applications:

   ```
    xscreensaver -nosplash
   ```
3. Disable default Super+L shortcut

   - Install CompizConfig Settings Manager

     ```
     sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
     ```
   - Launch it and click "Ubuntu Unity Plugin"
   - Click the button next to "Key to lock the screen."
   - Disable
4. Add this command to enable <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut for XScreenSaver in *System Settings* → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts* → *Custom Shortcuts*:

   ```
    xscreensaver-command -lock
   ```

Comment: How can I add `Super` (=`Windows button` / `CMD`) + `L` as a custom shortcut if pressing that makes me logout directly :) when I want to set the shortcut? /// found out myself. Go to Settings --> Keyboard Shortcuts --> roughly in the middle, you find the topic `System`, at the 3rd line, there is `Log out` with `Super`+`L` Shortcut. Click on it and give it something you do not need like `Super`+`;`. Then go down to `Custom Shortcuts` and add `Super`+`L` for the custom logout command.