# How do I prevent my display from turning off when screen is locked?

Tags: power-management, 16.10, lock-screen

First of all, I checked "[How to prevent my screens from turning off, when the screen is locked?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348974/how-to-prevent-my-screens-from-turning-off-when-the-screen-is-locked)" but that didn't help.

The laptop is set to not suspend no matter if it's running via battery or AC. Under "Brightness & Lock", the option "Turn screen off when inactive for" is set to "Never". Brightness is set to 100% and dimming is enabled.

When I lock the machine however, the display fades to blank and then the screen goes off. How do I prevent this?

Comment: @M.Becerra That duplicate candidate doesn't work for OP or for myself (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent my screens from turning off, when the screen is locked?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348974/how-to-prevent-my-screens-from-turning-off-when-the-screen-is-locked)

Answer (score 2):

Quite by accident tonight I discovered a "hack". Enter an invalid password at the lock screen and it will stay there and not fade to black.

I'll be using this technique myself from now on until a better answer comes along. The duplicate candidates don't work for me under Ubuntu 16.04 and like yourself it irritates me the screen turns off.

---

## Feb 20 2018 Update - Disable Dimming CLI method

To prevent screen from turning off you need two settings, one under battery power the other when plugged into wall outlet (A/C).

### For battery timeout:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout <time_in_seconds>
```

### For AC timeout:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout <time_in_seconds>
```

So for both Battery and A/C set the time to 0 (never).

### For Login screen:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

### Disable dimming screen when idle:

In [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257329/laptop-screen-dims-after-20-seconds-cannot-change-that/258886) someone complained when on battery screen dims every 20 seconds and wants to turn that feature off:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.