# Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop - Only suspend after 10 minutes on battery

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery, hibernate

I have an Ubunutu 20.04 Desktop. It suspends after certain time without activity, no matter if it is powered.

I want it to never suspend when powered, and suspend only after 10 minutes running on battery.
I don't want to completely disable all suspend/hibernation services.

Is it possible to config what I need?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it

1. Go to `settings` → `Power` → `automatic suspend` and change the time

:))

Comment: Hi Preldiot,

Automatic  Suspend is OFF for when plugged in. And it still suspend after a while inactive even plugged in.

Comment: Okay, in that case, I think, your system didn't attempt to suspend actually it goes to the lock screen and from there it gets suspended. You can verify this by pressing `super + L` on your system if the system gets suspended then this is the culprit. To solve this issue this might help you https://askubuntu.com/a/1008228/1112104