# How can I prevent my laptop to autamatically suspend?

Tags: boot, suspend, power-management, hibernate

Whenever I plugged in charger on my laptop, it gets suspend/sleep/hibernate. How can I fix it?
And after disabling suspend by running this command: sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

Then whenever I plugged in charger, light of the screen gets off and at that time keyboard and mouse is not working.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: this might help https://askubuntu.com/a/1337230/1112104 also go through the comments

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware failure than an OS-specific issue if the machine is reacting badly to having a power cord attached …

Comment: Check Settings - Power: ensure "Automatic suspend" is disabled there both on AC power and on battery. If this is correctly set, then add that information to your question (use "edit")

Comment: @vanadium After executing the command, which I have described in the discription. System will never choose to suspend either automatically or manually. Suspend option vanished from where we can choose to let suspend. So there is no need to do anything in setting.