# How to keep the locked screen on in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: screen, lock-screen, settings

Even though I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348974/how-to-prevent-my-screens-from-turning-off-when-the-screen-is-locked), Ubuntu automatically turns my monitors off the moment I lock the computer. Can you please let me how I can disable this feature? I use Ubuntu 16.04.5.

**What does NOT work:**

I have changed the following settings, and they are impact-less:

- Preventing automatic suspension
  [image: Preventing automatic suspension]
- Automatic Screen Turn off
  [image: Automatic Screen Turn off]